# Android: Add image on top of each item in a listview

Tags: android, android-listview

Does anyone know if it is possible to layer an image over the top of each item in a listview? To indicate that each list item is clickable, I'd like to add a small right-pointing arrow on the extreme right side of every item in the list. I'd like this image to scroll with the list.

I know that I can just create a horizontal linearlayout and put the image there, but this takes up some of the screen. I'd rather have it "floating" over the top of each item. Hopefully I'm making myself clear.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not create your `layout` to have this arrow thing and just hide/show it depending on the situation. Or get the `Layout` of the view that you are using and add this `ImageView` in it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: don't do this, it directly contradicts Android UX guidelines, http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Long answer: post your xml/code for building the cell. It's probably enough to use a RelativeLayout and align an ImageView to its right side.

Again, this is completely unnecessary and an anti-pattern on Android. Don't do it.